# Insert Table Inside a Row

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a script which contain two tables: `tbl1` is a main table, `tbl2` is a second table which I want to insert into a `tbl1` second row by using **Pure JavaScript**. It work perfectly, but my `tbl2` have some `html attribute`, it doesn't seen when i saw the code after inserted 
**note**: `tbl1` and `tbl2` both are same column header and there have two columns.

```js
function inserttbl2() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var celltr = row.insertCell(0);
    row.innerHTML = document.getElementById("tbl2").outerHTML;
}
```

```css
.myclass{
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>table 1</td>
    <td>table 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table 1</td>
    <td>table 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<button onclick="inserttbl2()">Insert</button>
<br />

<table id='tbl2' class='myclass'>
<tr>
<td>table 2</td>
<td>table 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

As you see, the `tbl2` doesn't have a `<table id=....>`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the regular `appendChild` for your case, like this:

```js
function inserttbl2() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    var row = table.insertRow(1);
    var celltr = row.insertCell(0);
    row.appendChild(document.getElementById("tbl2"));
}
```

```css
.myclass{
background-color: green;
color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="tbl1">
  <tr>
    <td>table 1</td>
    <td>table 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>table 1</td>
    <td>table 1</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<br />
<button onclick="inserttbl2()">Insert</button>
<br />

<table id='tbl2' class='myclass'>
<tr>
<td>table 2</td>
<td>table 2</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

It will insert full second table inside the first.

Comment: the tbl2 in your answer is no't a right position sir, can you sent tbl2 into a div then insert into tbl1 please ?